# finding integrating factor besides seperable

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I've encountered the equation I've also solved it by seperating. But, I read that It can be also solved by integrating factor. How come?

$$ y' = 1 + x + y + xy $$
$$ y' = (1+x)(1+y) $$
I know that an equation should be this format to use integrating factor
$$ dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x) $$
I can't express in that form the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y' = 1 + x + y + xy  = 1 + x + (1+x) y\Rightarrow y' - (1+x) y = 1+x.$$

Now you can use integration factor with $P(x) = -(1+x)$ and $Q(x) = 1+x$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$y'=1+x+y+xy$$ can be put in the "standard"  form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-(x+1)y=1+x$$
One integrant factor for the ODE is
$$\mu (x)=\exp\left[-\int (1+x)dx\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$y'=1+x+y+xy=1+x+y(1+x)=(1+x)(1+y)$$ from here we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1+x)(1+y)$$ and $$\frac{dy}{1+y}=(1+x)dx$$ if $$y\ne -1$$